# AngularJS $resource caching with deferreds

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I have a $resource factory which I have implemented utilizing a caching library (ngStorage ).  I added in caching of the resource to localstorage and have checks in place to ensure the cache is up to date and valid.

I am however running into several issues I am struggling with correcting.  The first of which is everytime I load the cached data, the cache checks with the server to see if there is new data to retrieve and cache.  After it gathers this data I want to have the last data point object stored in the cache so I know what the last point in time is within the cache.

The second issue is I want my view to wait for the cache to be created before the routechange is completed.  I have a resolve property set on my controller view, however I am not sure where to implement the $q promise to be able to resolve the promise and make sure the data is existant.

My code is as follows:

The $resource:

```
angular.module('resources.readings', ['ngResource', 'ngStorage']).
    factory('Reading', function($resource, $localStorage, $sessionStorage) {
        var resource = $resource('api/index.php/readings/:id', {}, {
            'update': {method: 'PUT'}
        });

        var readingsCache = $localStorage.$default({
            readings: [],
            lastReading: null,
            lastUpdate: null,
            newestReading: null,
            firstReading: null
        });

        var pageLimit = 1000;
function subtractDays(date, days) {
            var result = new Date(date);
            result.setDate(date.getDate() - days);
            return result;
        }

        var refreshCache = function(loadDefault) {
            var endDate = new Date(readingsCache.newestReading._time);
            if (loadDefault) {
                var startDate = subtractDays(endDate, 1).toISOString();
            } else {
                var startDate = new Date(readingsCache.lastReading._time).toISOString();
            }
            endDate = endDate.toISOString();
            resource.get({q: 'getCount', startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate}, function(response) {
                var numPages = Math.ceil(response.totalCount / pageLimit);
                for (var i = 0; i < numPages; i++) {
                    resource.query({startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate, limit: pageLimit, page: i}, function(response) {
                        response.forEach(function(val, index, theArray) {
                            readingsCache.readings.push(val);
                        });
                    }, function(data) {
                        //a single reading call has failed
                    });
                }
            }, function(data) {
                //failure of getting count
            });
        }

        resource.getLastUpdate = function() {
            resource.get({q: 'getLastUpdate'}, function(response) {
                //assume cache is empty and needs to be filled
                var loadDefault = true;
                //if we have cached data, and theres new data to get, don't load the default value of a day
                if (readingsCache.newestReading && readingsCache.newestReading._ID !== response._ID) {
                    readingsCache.lastReading = readingsCache.newestReading;
                    readingsCache.newestReading = response;
                    loadDefault = false;
                    refreshCache(loadDefault);
                } else if (!readingsCache.lastUpdate) {
                    readingsCache.newestReading = response;
                    refreshCache(loadDefault);
                }
                readingsCache.lastUpdate = new Date();
                //                readingsCache.firstReading = readingsCache.readings[readingsCache.readings.length - 1];
            }, function(data) {
                //timeout and try again
            });
            return readingsCache;
        }
return resource;
    });
```

And my route and controller:

```
angular.module('temperature.readings', ['resources.readings', 'highcharts-ng'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
            var deferredReadingCache = ['Reading', '$q', function(Reading, $q) {
                    return Reading.getLastUpdate();
             }];
$routeProvider
                    .when('/readings', {
                        templateUrl: 'js/app/readings/reading-list.tpl.html',
                        controller: 'ReadingsListCtrl',
                        resolve: {
                            readingCache: deferredReadingCache
                        }
                    })
}])
    .controller('ReadingsListCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$route', 'Reading',     function($scope, $location, $route, Reading) {
            $scope.order = '_ID';
            $scope.reverse = false;
            $scope.readingCache = $route.current.locals.readingCache;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up needing to do was creating one promise for the entire code block to return but also when the resource queries the server and loops over it to fill the cache I needed to add a resolve there as well to ensure the loop had completed filling the cache before allowing for rendering on the page.  Here is my "final" code:

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
            //assume cache is empty and needs to be filled
            var loadDefault = true;
            var cached = false;
            resource.get({q: 'getLastUpdate'}).$promise.then(function(response) {
                //if we have cached data, and theres new data to get, don't load the default value of an hour
                if (readingsCache.newestReading && readingsCache.newestReading._ID === response._ID) {
                    cached = true;
                    deferred.resolve(readingsCache);
                } else if (readingsCache.newestReading && readingsCache.newestReading._ID < response._ID) {
                    readingsCache.lastReading = readingsCache.newestReading;
                    readingsCache.newestReading = response;
                    loadDefault = false;
                } else if (!readingsCache.lastUpdate) {
                    readingsCache.newestReading = response;
                }

                readingsCache.lastUpdate = new Date();

                endDate = new Date(readingsCache.newestReading._time);
                if (loadDefault) {
                    startDate = subtractMinutes(endDate, 60).toISOString();
                } else {
                    startDate = new Date(readingsCache.lastReading._time).toISOString();
                }
                endDate = endDate.toISOString();
                if (cached) {
                    deferred.resolve(readingsCache);
                } else {
                    var totalCount = null;
                    resource.get({q: 'getCount', startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate}).$promise.then(function(response) {
                        var numPages = Math.ceil(response.totalCount / pageLimit);
                        totalCount = response.totalCount;
                        for (var i = 0; i < numPages; i++) {
                            resource.query({startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate, limit: pageLimit, page: i}).$promise.then(
                                    function(response) {
                                        response.forEach(function(val, index, theArray) {
                                            readingsCache.readings.push(val);
                                            if (readingsCache.readings.length >= totalCount) {
                                                if (loadDefault) {
                                                    readingsCache.firstReading = readingsCache.readings[0];
                                                }
                                                deferred.resolve(readingsCache);
                                            }
                                        });
                                    });
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
```